# Jenkins returns 403 when monit tries to access

Tags: jenkins, monit

jenkins is running on port 8085 and accessible via browser.
Monit always gets 403 when trying to access.

```
Remote Host 'jenkins'
  status                       Connection failed
  monitoring status            Monitored
  monitoring mode              active
  on reboot                    start
  port response time           FAILED to [jenkins.internal]:8085 type TCP/IP protocol HTTP
  data collected               Thu, 04 Nov 2021 09:11:52
```

What is the reason for this? I suppose monit simply issues a GET request on /

UPDATE: Ubuntu 18.04 on i5 Hardware,
monit config:

```
check host jenkins with address jenkins.internal
   every 3 cycles
   if failed port 8085 protocol http then alert
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information please ... Ubuntu version, hardware etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is, that Jenkins returns a 403,
together with

curl jenkins:8085

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
-->

</body></html>
```

From "normal" behaviour, like in Spring, I would expect a 302 with the redirect to the login page, not a 403 and a JS reload. I will open an issue at jenkins.